# Calculating expected value when only conditional probabilities are given

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Today I wanted to help someone with a probability exercise, it was like this:

If it's sunny today, it's gonna be sunny tomorrow with probability $0.7$. If it rains today, it will rain tomorrow with probability $0.8$.
(It can only either be sunny or rain).

Now the questions was to calculate the expected amount of sunny days in a year ($360$ days). Is that possible by knowing only the conditional probabilities? I couldn't figure it out..

Comment: have a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_Markov_chains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it be that $p$ denotes the probability that some fixed day will appear to be a sunny day.

Then the probability that the day after this day is sunny equals:
$$p\times0.7+\left(1-p\right)\times0.2$$ so that:$$p=p\times0.7+\left(1-p\right)\times0.2$$
and consequently $p=0.4$.

The expectation of the number of sunny days among $360$ is then $360\times0.4=144$.